# amcharts : can we give diffenrt color for gridLine in negetive value?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

how to change grid line color when it crosses zero value.  As you can see in below code, gridline for category axis is pink, i want to change it to be blue in negative value.  Can it be done using amchart library or javascript. Thanks in advance

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "category": "Research",
  "value": 450
}, {
  "category": "Marketing",
  "value": 1200
}, {
  "category": "Distribution",
  "value": 1850
}, {
  "category": "HR",
  "value": 850
}, {
  "category": "Sales",
  "value": 499
}, {
  "category": "Support",
  "value": 871
}, {
  "category": "Other",
  "value": -512
}];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = '#FF69B4';
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 1;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

how to change grid line color when it crosses zero value.  As you can see in below code, gridline for category axis is pink, i want to change it to be blue in negative value.  Can it be done using amchart library or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of something like below snippet:

```
"yAxes": [{
  "axisRanges": [{
      "value": 0,
      "endValue": -999,
      "axisFill": {
          "fill": "#ccc",
          "fillOpacity": 0.1
      },
      "grid": {
          "strokeOpacity": 0
      }
}]
```

Screenshot:
[image]